# Flask Security Confirm Register Form not adding new fields

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

Below is how I am trying to add extra fields to the confirm register form. When I enter my credentials in my application the application takes all the built in fields, sends it to my data base, and sends me a working confirmation email. However, the name, country, age fields are missing. I know the correct form is being used because the Captcha validate check is being done.

```
 class NHRegisterForm(ConfirmRegisterForm):
        name = db.StringField('Full Name', [DataRequired()])
        country = db.StringField('Country', [DataRequired()])
        age = db.StringField('Age', [DataRequired()])

        def validate(self):
            if not recaptcha.verify():
                self.password.errors = self.password.errors + ("Error completing ReCaptcha below", )
                return False
            return super(NHRegisterForm, self).validate()
```

This is how I am passing my custom forms into the flask security initializer.

```
security = Security(app, user_datastore, confirm_register_form=NHRegisterForm, login_form=NHLoginForm)
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also override the view to show those fields in the form.  See docs on how to override (basically create folder: templates/security) and add register_user.html form override with your new fields.